# How do I control / acquire the tilt angle of kinect v1? I am using freenect on ROS kinetic

Tags: linux, kinect, ros, openkinect

Hardware: Microsoft Kinect v1 ROS distro: kinetic version: v1.12.13

kinect_aux seems to be the driver which lets us access the accelerometer and tilt motor, but it is not available for ROS kinetic.

Also, I read somewhere that dynamic_reconfigure GUI is an alternative, but I can't seem to find the tilt angle. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Deprecated Use [libfreenect](https://github.com/ros-drivers/libfreenect) instead for Kinect v1 and libfreenect2 for Kinect v2